# Simple way to make animation character by character ( Kotlin )

Tags: android, kotlin

Show letter by letter in an easy way with kotlin Class
Like :
A
An
And
Andr
Andro
Androi
Android

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val textView = TextView(this)
val resultText = "Android"
Thread {
    for (i in 0..resultText.length) {
        runOnUiThread { textView.text = resultText.substring(0, i) }
        Thread.sleep(500)
    }
}.start()
```

You'll have to add `textView` to some parent, like your `contentView`.

Comment: A couple of caveats. This will leak the Activity instance for the total duration of the animation. If there are any characters that are bigger than a single code unit, you'll either have weird garbage appear as they are interpreted individually, or you'll have stutters in the animation because some characters will have longer gaps between them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You're right. For the leaking, I didn't find a way to do it without, have you got a better solution for that, like clearing a reference in `onDestroy`?

Comment: Coroutines are the easy way (see my answer). Without coroutines, create a property `private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`. Post your work to this handler instead of using `runOnUiThread`, and store a reference to it in another property `var textRunnable: Runnable? = null`, and in `onDestroy()` call `textRunnable?.let(handler::removeCallbacks)`. If it's possible you have more than one animation like this going, then you need a runnable property for each of them so they can each be cancelled. Or you could cancel the previous one each time you create a new one.

Comment: You could also do something with a WeakReference to the text view. This is also kinda messy.

Answer (score 0):

I like Cactusroot's answer better but here's another way to do it with a `Timer`

```
private fun animateCharacters(activity: Activity, str: String, animationIntervalMs: Long) {
    val chars = str.toCharArray().toMutableList()
    var cStr = ""

    val timer = Timer()
    val task = object: TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            activity.runOnUiThread {
                val char = chars.removeFirstOrNull()
                if (char == null) {
                    cancel()
                    return@runOnUiThread
                }

                cStr += char
                Log.i("Animated String", cStr)
                // update UI with new text
            }
        }
    }
    timer.schedule(task, 0, animationIntervalMs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the other answers (as of this writing):

1. It will leak the Activity for the duration of the animation. Suppose the user rotates the screen a few times quickly. There will be many outdated copies of the Activity in memory, still running useless animations.
2. They assume that all code points fit within a single code unit (Kotlin `char`). When there are longer code points you will get some weird behavior when you try to set text with the in-between state.

If you do this with a coroutine, it automatically will cancel itself when the activity is destroyed so the activity won't be leaked. This is much simpler than trying to manage threads or timers externally and cancelling them in `onDestroy()`.

To animate text correctly, you should add one code point at a time, not one code unit (Kotlin `Char`) at a time. This is still assuming there are no emoji in the String. To support emoji is very complicated and you would probably want to use an external library to handle it.

```
fun typeWrite(textView: TextView, text: String, intervalMs: Long) = lifecycleScope.launch {
    val numCodePoints = text.codePointCount(0, text.length)
    for (i in 0..numCodePoints) {
        textView.text = text.take(text.offsetByCodePoints(0, i))
        delay(intervalMs)
    }
}
```